# How to give solid colors to bar charts in flot

Tags: javascript, flot, bar-chart

I need to give solid colors to bar charts...
I have followed this link
[Bar chart Example](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2010/03/jquery-flot-stacked-bar-chart-example/)

But i want to give solid colors and also i need to change colors myself... how to do it...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First off, read the [API.txt](http://flot.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/API.txt), it answers all your questions.  Two things you need to do then.  When you specify that you want bars, set `fill: 1`, which tells flot to make the colors 100% opaque.  To specify a colour per series, just add a `color:'red'` to each data object.

So you end up with a data object like this:

```
var data = [
    {label: 'foo', color:'red', data: [[1,300], [2,300], [3,300], [4,300], [5,300]]},
    {label: 'bar', color:'blue', data: [[1,800], [2,600], [3,400], [4,200], [5,0]]},
    {label: 'baz', color:'yellow', data: [[1,100], [2,200], [3,300], [4,400], [5,500]]},
];
```

And flot options like this:

```
{
    series: {
        stack: 1,
        bars: {
            show: true,
            barWidth: 0.6,
            fill:1
        }
    }
}
```

See it in action here:  http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/kKdxt/

Comment: In `fill: 1`, the 1 means opacity 100%.  You may specify other values less than 1 to get varying degrees of opacity.  If you set `fill: true` you get a default opacity of roughly 50%.

Comment: what if I was using xaxis mode time