# Bar Chart Color in flot.js

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, flot

I created a bar chart using `flot.js`.

Each bar should be in different color MVC using `$.ajax`.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  dataType: 'json',
  url: '/eTechInternal/GetSalesData/',
  data: {
    Year: Year,
    Month: Month,
    ResellerId: ResellerId
  },
  error: function() {
    alert("An error occurred.");
  },
  success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      var dataset = [{
        label: "",
        data: data,
        color: "#5482FF"
      }];
      var ticks = [
        [0, "EndPoints"],
        [1, "Exchange"],
        [2, "Amazon Small"],
        [3, "Amazon Medium"],
        [4, "Amazon Large"],
        [5, "Amazon XLarge"],
        [6, "Amazon 2XLarge"],
        [7, "Amazon 4XLarge"]
      ];


      var options = {
        series: {
          bars: {
            show: true
          }
        },
        bars: {
          align: "center",
          barWidth: 0.5
        },
        xaxis: {
          axisLabel: "",
          axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
          axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
          axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial',
          axisLabelPadding: 10,
          ticks: ticks
        },

        legend: {
          noColumns: 0,
          labelBoxBorderColor: "#000000",
          position: "nw"
        },
        grid: {
          hoverable: true,
          borderWidth: 2,
          backgroundColor: {
            colors: ["#ffffff", "#EDF5FF"]
          }
        }
      };

      $.plot($("#flot-bar-chart"), dataset, options);
      $("#flot-bar-chart").UseTooltip();
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: tl;dr. Can you specify what is happening with your current code? Were you able to debug what is wrong?

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23273055/different-color-bars-for-flot-categories-bar-chart  or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311147/how-to-give-solid-colors-to-bar-charts-in-flot

Comment: As the linked questions and their answers show, you need to seprate your data into multiple data series because you can only specify a color for a data series not single data points.